# Parsing JSON in node.js

Tags: json, node.js, parsing

How will I parse the following JSON in node.js to extract the value of temp and city

```
{
"message":"",
"cod":"200",
"type":"base",
"calctime":"",
"units":"internal",
"count":1,
"list":
    [
        {"id":2823368,
        "coord":{"lat":47.666672,"lon":9.6},
        "name":"London",
        "main":{"temp":275.79,"pressure":1020,"humidity":74,"temp_min":272.59,"temp_max":281.48},
        "dt":1362137169,
        "date":"2013-03-01 11:26:09",
        "wind":{"speed":1.5,"deg":0},
        "clouds":{"all":90},
        "weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],
        "sys":{"country":"DE","population":18135},
        "url":"http:\/\/openweathermap.org\/city\/2823368"
        }
        ]
}
```

I get the above JSON by:

```
var response = JSON.parse(body);

console.log(response);
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following to get temp and city (city from url) or else use name

```
var temp = response.list[0].main.temp,
url = response.list[0].url,
city = url.split('/')[3],
name = response.list[0].name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var temp = response.list[0].main.temp;
var city = response.list[0].name;
```

As for "city" I'm not sure what you're looking for since there's no key by that name in your input, but I took a guess.